# Creating 2 DNS names for 2 domains on one static IP - Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, dns, bind, domain-server

I have VPS Ubuntu 15.04 and there I have configured DNS for one of my external domains.

This is sample of configuration at '/etc/bind/named.conf.local':

```
zone "test.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/test.com.db";
        };
```

and inside '/etc/bind/zones/test.com.db'

```
$TTL 600
test.com.      IN      SOA     ns1.test.com. admin.test.com. (
                                                        2006081401
                                                        28800
                                                        3600
                                                        604800
                                                        38400
)

test.com.      IN      NS              ns1.test.com.
test.com.      IN      NS              ns2.test.com.

test.com.      IN      MX     10       mta.test.com.

test.com.       IN      A       111.111.111.111
*                       IN      A       111.111.111.111

ns1.test.com.              IN      A       111.111.111.111
ns2.test.com.              IN      A       111.111.111.111

www              IN      A       111.111.111.111
mta
```

Now if I want to use one more domain sample 'test.info' what do I need to do here?

Maybe create new zone and zone file like??:

```
zone "test.info" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/test.info.db";
        };
```

and zones/test.info.db like ??

```
$TTL 600
test.info.      IN      SOA     ns1.test.info. admin.test.info. (
                                                        2006081401
                                                        28800
                                                        3600
                                                        604800
                                                        38400
)

test.info.      IN      NS              ns1.test.info.
test.info.      IN      NS              ns2.test.info.

test.info.      IN      MX     10       mta.test.info.

test.info.       IN      A       111.111.111.111
*                       IN      A       111.111.111.111

ns1.test.info.              IN      A       111.111.111.111
ns2.test.info.              IN      A       111.111.111.111

www              IN      A       111.111.111.111
mta
```

Or I just need to create new zone record like:

```
zone "test.info" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/test.com.db";
        };
```

and point it to first domain 'test.com.db' file ?

Comment: My advice is to create new zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION WAS: I created new zone file for second domain and also new db file. So both domains have separated files.